# Universal PHP Scripting to Find Home Directory and .ssh Folder

Tags: php, ssh

I'm writing a script that will pull a given remote git branch into a webserver using php.

The first step in the process is to check to see if the webserver has a public key created.

I'm trying to make this as universal as I can for different server types ie: linux, windows etc. and I'm wondering if anyone has any ideas on how to determine the location of .ssh storage in different environments?

I have no idea what it is on other servers, nor do I know how to determine the user's home directory for different admin panels.

For instance in a normal cpanel server the location per user is always:

/home/username/.ssh/

But in Direct Admin it would be:

/home/username/domains/www.yourdomain.com/.ssh/ (or something similar)

I'm assuming that the ssh directory would always be within the users home directory above the doc root somewhere ... is it feasible to just search for a directory names .ssh?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

--Vince

Comment: On Windows it's `C:\Users\username\.ssh`. At least if PuTTY isn't being used.

Comment: Thanks @neubert that's part of it.